# How to Fetch Specific data column from Geoserver WMS layer using openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver, wms, openlayers-6

I have a layer in Geoserver, which I am showing on the HTML webpage using [openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html), but it has a lot of columns,

and I want to show the specific 1-2 columns of the table only " **by passing the string of column name** ", instead of whole table.

Is there any way possible?

```
      map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var myviewResolution = myview.getResolution();
        var url = india_dist_rainfall_layer_source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          myviewResolution,
          'EPSG:4326',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': '5'},
          
        );
        if (url) {
          fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
            .then(function (html) {
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
            });
        }
      });
```

[image: getFeatureInfoUrl]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WMS vendor option [`propertyName`](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#propertyname)

```
var url = india_dist_rainfall_layer_source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          myviewResolution,
          'EPSG:4326',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 
           'FEATURE_COUNT': '5',
           'propertyName': 'forecastDate,rainfall'},  
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could request the data in [another format](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) (e.g. JSON) and process it in your own code to give exactly the format that you need.

Alternatively, you could create a [FreeMarker template](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) to customise the HTML output.